# Filter pandas dataframe by date < another date where date is in an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (from the Binance API) indexed by symbol then date:

```
                    open      high       low     close        volume
symbol  date                                                            
BTCUSDT 2017-08-17   4261.48   4485.39   4200.74   4285.08    795.150377
        2017-08-18   4285.08   4371.52   3938.77   4108.37   1199.888264
        2017-08-19   4108.37   4184.69   3850.00   4139.98    381.309763
        2017-08-20   4120.98   4211.08   4032.62   4086.29    467.083022
        2017-08-21   4069.13   4119.62   3911.79   4016.00    691.743060
                      ...       ...       ...       ...           ...
        2021-11-10  66947.67  69000.00  62822.90  64882.43  65171.504050
        2021-11-11  64882.42  65600.07  64100.00  64774.26  37237.980580
        2021-11-12  64774.25  65450.70  62278.00  64122.23  44490.108160
        2021-11-13  64122.22  65000.00  63360.22  64380.00  22504.973830
        2021-11-14  64380.01  65550.51  63576.27  65519.10  25705.073470
```

I need to filter by date, such as date < '2021-11-11' (where '2021-11-11' is a datetime object matching the date column type).

I can get this to work via:

`df = df[df['date'] < utc_datetime]`

if date is not in an index.

I've investigated df.filter(), read the pandas documentation, and googled extensively (and searched SO) before posting.

If this is obvious my apologies, please just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the expected output was obvious from my problem description.  I've shared a sample dataframe, and I need to return a dataframe with the rows filtered on date < some other date.  In general I have an aversion to relying on sort order to return the correct data, and the data volumes are not so great that the performance gain would be noticeable.  But I'll also try your approach and keep it in mind.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('date') < utc_datetime]
```

Or [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = df[df.index.droplevel(0) < utc_datetime]
```

Or convert `MultiIndex` to columns, but then different index, so converting to numpy array:

```
df = df[df.reset_index()['date'].to_numpy() < utc_datetime]
```